# Retrofit 2 сервер возвращает 400, в postman OK

Tags: android, retrofit2

Когда я отправляю GET/POST запрос с заголовком **Authorization** сервер сразу мне посылает ответ 400 в виде HTML

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 400 https://api.didido.staj.fun/api/v1/users/user_id (281ms)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: server: nginx
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: date: Thu, 08 Sep 2022 11:18:01 GMT
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: content-length: 150
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <html>
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <body>
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <hr><center>nginx</center>
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: </body>
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: </html>
```

А вот что я посылаю на сервер.

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> GET https://api.didido.staj.fun/api/v1/users/user_id
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Accept: application/json
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJh.bGciOiJSUzI1O...
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> END GET
```

Сервер почему-то не хочет принимать от меня запросы, в которых содержится **Authorization**, если без него, данные доходят. Смотрел в логах на сервере

Непосредственно сам Retrofit

```
@Headers("Accept: application/json")
@GET("users/user_id")
suspend fun userId(
    @Header("Authorization") authHeader : String
) : Response<LoginResponse> 


var client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(Interceptor { chain ->
        val newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .build()
        chain.proceed(newRequest)
    }).build()

    fun getClient(baseUrl: String): Retrofit {

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
```

Пробовал в клиенте добавлять заголовок `.addHeader("Authorization", token)` и такой `.header("Authorization", token)` не помогло, пробовал в `@Headers` добавить напрямую, тоже ошибка 400.

А вот в **postman приходит ответ**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С этим токеном пользователь не найдет, но на самом деле тут будет ответ **success**

Comment: А в постмане-то как запрос выглядит? Должна быть разница.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja я обновил ответ

Comment: Может User-Agent обязателен? Добавляйте по одному заголовки и смотрите что получается.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja  пробовал ранее так делать, и сейчас попробовал, та же ошибка. Сейчас попробуй в клиенте прописать

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja получилось! Сейчас гляну почему получал ошибку

Comment: Загадка, у меня несколько клиентов. Будет решение, дам знать.